# Find matches from multiple lists and combine matches based on 3 of 4 items

Tags: python, list

New to Python - Forgive any newbie-type syntax! If my code can be made more efficient in any way, please help there as well.

My question today is to make the output more efficient.

The input file I use, has raw data (from a Firewall Log) that looks like this:

```
loc=15100850|time= 2Dec2016 22:30:17|action=accept|orig=10.10.10.10|i/f_dir=inbound|i/f_name=bond1|product=VPN-1 & FireWall-1|rule=126|rule_uid={10295A8E-3C83-11E5-A372-0A74A015A1A1}|rule_name=DP Syslog|src=10.10.10.10|s_port=51726|dst=10.10.10.10|service=514|proto=udp|__policy_id_tag=product=VPN-1 & FireWall-1[db_tag={CEACB4D6-DAE9-5141-A60F-2913D9FEF3F1};mgmt=CMA-WIN;date=1480655908;policy_name=fw1c-dca_b-win
```

The Python code I've written will extract the pertinent data I need and format it to look like this (and remove duplicates):

```
10.180.1.1      10.100.100.1    TCP 514
10.180.2.1      10.100.100.1    TCP 514
10.20.20.20     50.50.50.50     TCP 80
10.20.20.20     20.20.20.30     TCP 80
```

What I need to do now is combine these results based on 3 of 4 that match

for instance:

The first two lines above can be combined since the dest, proto, & service all match. To be written to file as:

```
10.180.1.1;10.180.2.1 <tab> 10.100.100.1 <tab> TCP 514
```

The third and forth lines above can be combined since the source, proto & service all match. To be written to file as:

```
10.20.20.20 <tab> 50.50.50.50;20.20.20.30 <tab> TCP 80
```

However, if multiple service objects are found, they will need to be written to file separated by comma's not semicolons with on ONE proto....i.e

10.20.20.20  50.50.50.50  TCP 443, 80, 8080

Is something like this possible?

```
import re
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

def connection_list(filename):
    try:
        with open(filename, "r") as file:
            text = file.read()
    except IOError:
        print(filename, "Does not exist in the current directory. Are you in the correct directory???")

    sources = re.findall(r'src=(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})', text)
    dest = re.findall(r'dst=(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})', text)
    service = re.findall(r'service=(\d+)', text)
    proto = re.findall(r'proto=(\w+)', text)

    proto = [item.upper() for item in proto]
    sources = [item.split('=')[1] for item in sources]
    dest = [item.split('=')[1] for item in dest]

    with open("output.txt", "w") as TufinReq:
        for item in zip(sources, dest, proto, service):
            TufinReq.write('{}\t{}\t{} {}\n'.format(*item))

    f=open("output.txt", "r")
    list = []
    for line in f:
        if line not in list:
            list.append(line)
    f.close()
    f=open("output.txt", "w+")
    for line in list:
        f.write(line)
    f.close()

connection_list(filename)
```

Comment: (1) This question would be much better if you left out the stuff about parsing and files and just asked how to merge a list of lists in the way you describe. Stick to what's strictly relevant. (2) Why do you write to a file and then read it? Remove the duplicates before you write anything. (3) Use with statements for every file operation. (4) You say 2 of 3 in the title but 3 of 4 in the description. (5) What if I have to merge lines 1 and 2 but also 2 and 3 based on different common fields, e.g. `A B C D; A B C E; A B F E`?

Answer (score 0):

You'll be storing it in your own way, but let's assume input is a list of lists:

```
a = """
    10.180.1.1      10.100.100.1    TCP 514
    10.180.2.1      10.100.100.1    TCP 514
    10.20.20.20     50.50.50.50     TCP 80
    10.20.20.20     20.20.20.30     TCP 80
"""
a = [line.strip().split() for line in a.split('\n') if line.strip()]
```

Now, `itertools.groupby` is one way to go:

```
# use itertools.groupby, with a (hashable version of) all but the first item in each list
import itertools
keyfunc = lambda x: tuple( x[1:] )
grouped = itertools.groupby(sorted(a, key=keyfunc), key=keyfunc)

# There are now a number of ways you could walk through/format the result - here's one:
b = { key:[src for src,dst,service,proto in values]  for key, values in grouped }
```

`collections.defaultdict`, or the code below which uses an equivalent approach, is also a way to go:

```
b = {}
for src, dst, service, proto in a:
    b.setdefault((dst, service, proto), []).append(src)
```

Either way, the input and output look like this:

```
>>> a
[['10.180.1.1', '10.100.100.1', 'TCP', '514'],
 ['10.180.2.1', '10.100.100.1', 'TCP', '514'],
 ['10.20.20.20', '50.50.50.50', 'TCP', '80'],
 ['10.20.20.20', '20.20.20.30', 'TCP', '80']]

>>> b
{('10.100.100.1', 'TCP', '514'): ['10.180.1.1', '10.180.2.1'],
 ('20.20.20.30', 'TCP', '80'): ['10.20.20.20'],
 ('50.50.50.50', 'TCP', '80'): ['10.20.20.20']}
```

Note that you'll have to take additional steps if it's important to preserve any information about the order of the entries.

Comment: Thank you! The more I learn about Python, the more I realize just how much left I have to learn! If you the time, can you show me the steps necessary to keep the order, as the output will turn into a firewall rule, so Source - Destination-Proto-Service(port) do need to be in order.

Comment: They are in order in the sense that dest proto service port are kept in that sequence. It's just that the *chronological* order of the entries (original order in which different lines appear in the log) will not be preserved if you use a `dict` as I have here.